# When to use map reduce over Aggregation Pipeline in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

While looking at [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) for map-reduce, I found that:

> NOTE:
>
> For most aggregation operations, the Aggregation Pipeline provides
>   better performance and more coherent interface. However, map-reduce
>   operations provide some flexibility that is not presently available in
>   the aggregation pipeline.

I did not understand much from it.

- What are the use cases for using map-reduce over aggregation pipeline?
- What flexibility does map-reduce provide?
- How much delta is there in performance?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For one thing, Map/Reduce in MongoDB wasn't made for ad-hoc queries, there's considerable overhead to M/R. Even a very simple M/R operation on a small dataset can take in the hundreds of milliseconds because of that overhead.

I can't say much about the performance of M/R compared to the aggregation framework on large datasets in practice, but in theory, M/R operations on a large sharded database should be faster since the shards can run the operations largely in parallel.

As to the flexibility, since M/R actually runs javascript methods you have the full power of the language at your disposal. For example, let's say you wanted to group some data by the cosine of a field's value. Since there's neither a `$cos` operator in the aggregation framework, nor a meaningful way to build discrete buckets from continuous numbers (something like `$truncate`), the aggregation framework wouldn't help in that case.

So, in a nutshell, I'd say the use cases are

- keeping the results of M/R in a separate collection and updating it from time to time (using the `out` parameter and merging the results)
- Complex queries on large sharded data sets
- Queries that are so complex that you can't use the aggregation framework. I'd say that's a pretty certain sign of a design flaw in the data structure, but in principle, it can help